# UNHANDLED EXCEPTION In Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Can you help me about this?
I can't understand this error! :(

[image: Error Message]

Activity Code:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace Phoneword2
{
    [Activity(Label = "Phone Word", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            EditText phoneNumberText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.PhoneNumberText);
            Button translateButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.TranslateButton);
            Button callButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.CallButton);

            callButton.Enabled = false;

            // Add code to translate number

            string translatedNumber = "";

            translateButton.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                // Translate user's alphanumeric phone number to numeric
                translatedNumber = Core.PhonewordTranslator.ToNumber(phoneNumberText.Text);
                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(translatedNumber))
                {
                    callButton.Text = "Call";
                    callButton.Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    callButton.Text = "Call " + translatedNumber;
                    callButton.Enabled = true;
                }
            };

            callButton.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                // On "Call" button click, try to dial phone number.
                var callDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                callDialog.SetMessage("Call " + translatedNumber + "?");
                callDialog.SetNeutralButton("Call", delegate {
                    // Create intent to dial phone
                    var callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCall);
                    callIntent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("tel:" +
                    translatedNumber));
                    StartActivity(callIntent);
                });
                callDialog.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", delegate { });
                // Show the alert dialog to the user and wait for response.
                callDialog.Show();
            };

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it


        }
    }
}

`
```

And this is main.axml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:text="Enter a Phoneword"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/PhoneNumberText" />
    <Button
        android:text="Translator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/TranslateButton" />
    <Button
        android:text="Call"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/CallButton" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Its Contain two button and a plain text...
you can click at translate to updates the text of the Call button.
when you press call button, call to target number.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to make the last line of your `OnCreate` method its second line. In other words, remove / cut the following line of code from where it is

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
```

and paste it right after `base.OnCreate (bundle);`

Basically the first thing you need to do right after calling the `OnCreate` of parent is to tell the activity which layout to use. Once the activity knows that, only then it can find a control within that particular layout.

So your `OnCreate` method now becomes:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    EditText phoneNumberText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.PhoneNumberText);
    Button translateButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.TranslateButton);
    Button callButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.CallButton);

    callButton.Enabled = false;

    // Removed code for brevity //
}
```

Comment: Please see the new pic.

Comment: @SeyedMiladEmadi - this is strange as you should not be getting the error in that particular line of code. I can suggest two things: First, clean the solution and then rebuild it. Second, can you share a sample project in which you are facing the issue? I can try to run it myself to further look into it

Comment: I have a feeling that first option will work because the error does not make sense in that specific line plus the line of error has not changed...in both images it is line 24! So cleaning and rebuilding (perhaps even restarting Visual Studio) should work. Do let me know

Comment: can you share a sample project?